# How to white list a directory for ctrlp in vim

Tags: vim, ctrlp

Ctrlp currently searches/indexes my entire home directory, how can I tell it to only index `~/code`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have [several options](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim#basic-options) to configure where CtrlP will search for files. You will have to add these to your `.vimrc` file.

For example, in my case I use `ag` to perform the search:

```
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -l --hidden --nocolor -g "" --ignore .git'
```

Normally CtrlP will look into the directory of the current project. If you always want to search in `~/code` like you ask, you could add this custom command (in OSX):

```
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'find ~/code -type f ! -path "*.git*"'
```

You could even add extra directories, like:

```
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'find ~/code ~/foo ~/bar -type f ! -path "*.git*"'
```

However, I advise to not fix the directory where CtrlP will look and leave it to search for the project of the current file (see `let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode`)

Answer (score 1):

CtrlP searches/indexes your entire home directory because that's what you ask it to do.

You are probably starting Vim in your `$HOME` and doing `:CtrlP` from there. Since the working directory is `$HOME` you shouldn't be surprised that CtrlP scans all of it.

The solution to this non-issue is simply to use your shell and Vim as they are supposed to be used:

```
$ cd ~/code
$ vim
```